# Box shadow for bottom side only

Tags: css

I have an box of content and need to give shadow for that. But I want to give shadow for the bottom of the box only. I used this `css box-shadow: 0 3px 5px #000000;`

If i give this code it shows left,right and bottom. I need bottom only

Can any one suggest to solve this one. Thanks a lot

Comment: this will be useful  http://css3gen.com/box-shadow/ create your own :)

Comment: http://silviarebelo.com/demos/boxgenerator/ This site will give you understanding of how box-shadow works

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You can do the following after adding class `one-edge-shadow` or use as you like.

```
.one-edge-shadow {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
       -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
            box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
}
```

**[Source](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-box-shadow/)**

Answer (score 15):

You have to specify `negative spread` in the box shadow to remove side shadow

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 10px 10px -10px #000000;
   -moz-box-shadow: 0 10px 10px -10px #000000;
        box-shadow: 0 10px 10px -10px #000000;
```

Check out http://dabblet.com/gist/9532817 and try changing properties and know how it behaves

Answer (score 0):

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 5px -3px #000;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 5px -3px #000;
box-shadow: 0 3px 5px -3px #000;
```

Comment: While this likely answers the question it's often best to explain *why* or provide informative links.

Answer (score 0):

Specify negative value to spread value. 
This works for me:

```
box-shadow: 0 2px 3px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
```