# Box Shadow for textfield only bottom

Tags: html, css

I'm not very familiar with box shadow and i want to make a text field with only bottom box shadow for my web,
here's what the code look like:

```
input[type="text"], input[type="email"],  textarea{ box-shadow: 0 0 0 1.5px, 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.08) inset}
```

this code generating full shadow box for textfield and text area, i want only bottom part to get the shadow box, i already saw [box-shadow bootom solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12798902/box-shadow-for-bottom-side-only) but i dont get it what to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below codes, creates bottom shadow for input and textarea and use `:focus` instead of `:active`.

```
input[type="text"], input[type="email"],  textarea{ 
border:none;
box-shadow:1px 1px 10px 5px rgba(1,1,1,0.2);
transition: 0.6s ease;
}

input[type="text"]:focus, input[type="email"]:focus,  textarea:focus{ 
box-shadow:0px 10px 10px -8px rgba(1,1,1,0.8);
}
```

```css
input[type="text"], input[type="email"],  textarea{ 
border:none;
box-shadow:1px 1px 10px 5px rgba(1,1,1,0.2);
transition: 0.6s ease;
margin-bottom:50px;
float:left;
width:100%;
height:20px;
}
textarea{
height:150px;
}
input[type="text"]:focus, input[type="email"]:focus,  textarea:focus{ 
box-shadow:0px 10px 10px -8px rgba(1,1,1,0.8);
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
<input type="email">
<textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: thanks its working, but i want to add modified code, so when the textfield and textarea active they become full shadowbox, but the problem is i need to hold my click so they become full, when i release it, it backs to only bottom box shadow only, but the textarea is working fine only the textfield, here's the code `input[type="text"]:active, input[type="email"]:active,  textarea:active{
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1.5px, 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.08) inset;
}`

Answer (score 1):

use bottom shadow in css

```
.one-edge-shadow {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
       -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
            box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This code will add a bottom shadow across all browsers for all elements,

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 11px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 11px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
box-shadow: 0px 11px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
```

Comment: thanks its working, but i want to add modified code, so when the textfield and textarea active they become full shadowbox, but the problem is i need to hold my click so they become full, when i release it, it backs to only bottom box shadow only, but the textarea is working fine only the textfield, here's the code `input[type="text"]:active, input[type="email"]:active,  textarea:active{
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1.5px, 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.08) inset;
}`

Answer (score 0):

try this. i found this on [How to make shadow on border-bottom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971880/how-to-make-shadow-on-border-bottom)

```
 div{
        -webkit-box-shadow:0px 1px 1px #de1dde;
         -moz-box-shadow:0px 1px 1px #de1dde;
         box-shadow:0px 1px 1px #de1dde;
          }
        <div>wefwefwef</div>
```